# How to align right in flex?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components

In my react `styled-component` i have a Flex component with a couple of children and a separate component:

```
<Flex align="center" justify="flex-end" flex="1 0 auto" px={[12, 18]}>
  {children}
  <AlertBell path={pathname} />
</Flex>
```

I am trying to align children and `AlertBell` component to the right. However when I add more margin to the `AlertBell` the children do not move to the left. How can I align the elements right even when increasing the margin in `AlertBell`?

Comment: Do you refer to children of `AlertBell` or `Flex` container? Margin on each sides?

Comment: Of the Flex container

Answer (score 0):

There are slight differences in the required syntax:

```
<Flex alignItems="center" justifyContent="flex-end" flex="1 0 auto" px={[12, 18]}>
    {children}
    <AlertBell path={pathname} />
</Flex>
```

`alignItems="center"` is also the default in the current version. `flex` prop would not be required for this to work, as it applies to the wrapper itself.